# CodeIgniter post is not working when input value is more 1000 chars

Tags: codeigniter, post

I have a form contains inputs, it works fine till I include the following input field with more 1000 chars value and the problem is the form posts nothing to my controller.

It works fine in my localhost but when I upload it to my remote host the problem is happen.

```
<form action="controllerName/test" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="test1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="test2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="imgBase64" value="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGQCAYAAAByNR6YAAAgAElEQVR4nO
 ......">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[image]

Post Result:

```
array()
```

Error:

```
Forbidden 403
```

Comment: Do you want to upload using base64? why don't you want to upload the file to your server and save path of the database?

Comment: No, this is the highchart convas, I want to write it to a file in controller

Comment: Deleted my answer in light of additional information. I just passed a 2000 char hidden variable and it worked fine on my server. It almost has to be some kind of server config issue.